# Animate a circle around the circumference of another big circle

Tags: css, animation, svg

I want to move a small circle around the circumference of the big circle using only CSS.

```css
@keyframes moveAround {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#small {
  animation: moveAround 2s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify which coordinate the circle should rotate around. By default, this is coordinate `0,0`, but you want it to orbit the center of the large circle.

In CSS, you do this with [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin):

```css
#small {
    transform-origin: 60px 50px;
    animation: moveAround 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes moveAround {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
        <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
        <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

A CSS only solution with no SVG

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 20px solid #2493AB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #EF6868;
  animation: moveAround 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moveAround {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(40px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translate(40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

*Pure SMIL SVG solution*

To rotate the ball, use  [animateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform)

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s"
         dur="3s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50"
          repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

*Ball rotation with pauses between full revolutions*

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform id="an"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s;an.end+1s"
         dur="2s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50"
           /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

*Back and forth rotation*

```html
<svg width="120" height="100" viewBox="0 0 120 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="circles">
      <circle id="big" cx="60" cy="50" r="30" fill="white" stroke="#2493AB" stroke-width="20" />
      <circle id="small" cx="60" cy="20" r="10" fill="#EF6868" >
       <animateTransform
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="0s"
         dur="4s"
         values="
           0 60 50;
           360 60 50;
           360 60 50;
           0 60 50;
           0 60 50"
          repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea with single div.

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(#EF6868 0 9.5px, transparent 10.5px) 50% 0% / 20px 20px no-repeat, 
              radial-gradient(transparent 29px, #2493AB 30px 50px) 0 0 / 100% 100% no-repeat;
  animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```